# Is it a bad practice to use OOP to create "collections" for almost every site component?

Tags: php, oop, class

I mean like for everything, for example:

instead of-

```
// this does a directory scan and returns an array of "Component" objects.
$extensions = get_site_extensions($path);
```

do this-

```
$extension_factory = new ComponentCollection($path);


// does the same thing as the function above
$extensions = $extension_factory->getList();
```

Should I just stick with a simple function?

Comment: What do these "collections" do?

Comment: well nothing much :) right now I only have that getList() method there. I was thinking it is a good idea to wrap it inside a class, in case I decide in the future to extend it. Is it wrong thinking?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, if the collection is only going to be an array of items then the collection class is probably an overkill but if you want some more functionality to specially handle components then it can be a good idea.

Comment: if you just want an object, e.g. no additional methods and type not important, then use `new ArrayIterator(get_site_extensions())` or `new ArrayObject(get_site_extensions())` or `SplFixedArray::fromArray(get_site_extensions())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAGNI comes to mind.  It's bad practice to write code 'just in case'.  Another way of thinking about it:  what problem is your code solving?  If the code isn't immediately getting you closer to your finished app, don't include it.

You may also want to familiarize yourself with some patterns and anti-patterns to understand what they accomplish and when and why you would (or not) use them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Anything that could be objectized, as in there would be more of the same of it (for instance, extensions, plugins, resources, data structures etc), should written as a class.

Which means that your extension factory should be written as a class, as well as the extension itself (probably). Just be careful with the use of factories, they often disregard the law of dependency injection.

Comment: that was exactly what I was thinking - to turn **everything** that can become an object to ...objects.

Comment: In Java for instance, an object becomes a valid variable type. So an object of type Extension is instantiated like so: `Extension extension = new Extension()`. Your factory sounds more like a class than an object (meaning it should be static), as there is only one factory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do this for *everything* that might *ever* be extended, your code surely will look like a big mess.

You are the only one who can decide whether in this particular case it makes sense. We can't help, because we don't know anything about your app...